# How you will deal with this situation? API Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, okhttp

Let me show you how I'm dealing with this

I'm getting a response from an API using the GET method; the response is something like that.

available{
}

So, right now it is empty, but in any second response could be something like that.

available{
Id: 12145214522654
}

I need that ID and it comes in a second and vanish in 2 or 3 seconds

Right now I'm using a for loop to run the GET method every second in the background and when I get a result a new method call and then the same back-to for loop. But for loop is not a good thing to use in the background and I'm hitting too much on API, is there any other solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use push notification(FCM). The server can send you a notification when the ID is available. Or if you need more reliability, you can use WebSockets.

Comment: Thanks for you answer could you please tell me how can I use WebSockets? I'm newbie so don't know much about it. Appreciate if you provide me any link of tutorial which helps me out.
Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/android-and-mqtt-a-simple-guide-cb0cbba1931c